# Foreach loop with doParallel in R is not working

Tags: r, foreach, multicore, doparallel

I am writing an R script that parse a large json file, takes the first 250k lines and output two different files. I wrote the following `for` loop that works just fine.

```
for(i in 1:4) {
  print(paste0("Iteration", " ", i))
  db <- read_lines(file = "February.jsonl", 
                   skip = 250000*i,
                   n_max = 250000)
  
  df <- stream_in(textConnection(db),
                  pagesize = 1000)
  rm(db)  
  
  tweets <- df %>%
    filter(lang=="en") %>%
    select(id_str, created_at, full_text,
           retweet_count,
           favorite_count, lang)
  txt <- tweets %>%
    select(full_text)%>%
    mutate(br = "***") %>%
    unite("tw", full_text:br)
  
  out_txt <- paste0("February",
                    "_", i, ".txt")
  out_csv <- paste0("feb-tw",
                    "_", i, ".csv")
  
  write.csv(tweets, out_csv, 
            fileEncoding = "UTF-8",
            row.names = FALSE)
  
  write.table(txt$tw, out_txt, 
              fileEncoding = "UTF-8",
              row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE)
  
  rm(list = ls())
  
}
```

However, since the file is really huge, it would be useful to process the loop with all the avaible CPU. I tried using `doParallel` and `foreach` adding this at the top of the code

```
library (doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores()-1)

foreach(i = 1:5) %dopar% {
  library(jsonlite)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(readr)
#same code below
```

This crashes after five minutes of computing with an unknown error. It seems to me that the code is not being executed since I cannot even see the first line of the loop with the `print` statement.

Comment: `foreach` loops are fundamentally different to `for` loops, especially if run in parallel. The parallel workers have no access to the main R session and can therefore not print to it.

Comment: You mean that the problem is that I requested the ```foreach``` loop to print? Or this is not related to the error?

Comment: I don't know why this fails, you don't even provide a reproducible example. I'm just pointing out that copying the code from a `for` loop into a `foreach` loop and expecting this to "just work" in parallel is a pretty naive approach and indicates that you haven't studied the excellent foreach package vignettes.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to provide you a rep example, is 60GB of json file...I'm not a developer, I'm a linguist. I write in R and Python because I need to, for my research. Yes, I haven't studied the vignettes and yes, that's a naive approach. So what? The point of asking questions is to learn things that you don't already know :)

Comment: Well, we don't need a 60GB file for a reproducible example. If your `foreach` code is identical to your `for` code, you are doing it wrong. Sorry, can't help you more than this.

Comment: Fair enough. As I wrote the code is identical, I just added  the `foreach` and reloaded my libraries. Given that is wrong, what should I change then?

Comment: I don't know how the parallel workers access the global environment, but ending the loop with rm is, I think, not a good idea. If one worker is finished before the others, then he might remove all of the objects that are needed by the other ones.

Comment: @glagla No, that's not possible. Each worker is independent from all other workers and doesn't have access to the environment of the main process.